# Find rows with same non-null values

Tags: sqlite, join, null, subset, sql-null

This seems like a rather straightforward problem, yet I have not been able to find the solution:

In a table `test`, I have some subset of columns which I am interested in, say `a,b,c,d,e,f`.

Some or most of these columns are `NULL`, but at least one is always filled.

Now for some rows, returned, say by:

```
SELECT rowid,a,b,c,d,e,f LIMIT 1;
```

I would like to get the number of rows which have the same non-null values.
So for example if `a,d,f` are the columns that are not `NULL` for this row, the result would be the same as for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM test WHERE a=a_ AND d=d_ AND f=f_ 

SELECT a as a_, d as d_, f as f_ FROM test LIMIT 1;
```

How can this be done in one step / line? Or do I need a temporary table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `IS` to compare safely values that may be `NULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM test LIMIT 1) t2
ON (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f) IS (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f);
```

or with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM test LIMIT 1)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM test t1 INNER JOIN cte t2
ON (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f) IS (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e, t2.f);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2a32d2ed94d6a55f4179822e84ed86b7).

Comment: Thanks! Not needing the aliases means I can also use for example `a` on both sides essentially?

Comment: @RadioControlled yes you can if they are all properly qualified with the table's alias, like `t2.a`

Comment: You are welcome to simplify your code without the aliases if you like.

Comment: @RadioControlled done and it looks better.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I just realized that there was a misunderstanding: I am looking for all rows where the value in t1 is either NULL or equals the respective value in t2...

Comment: @RadioControlled this is a different requirement than: "I would like to get the number of rows which have **the same non-null values**", for which you should ask another question.